# Chrome fonts not displaying properly after installing texlive

Tags: 11.04, fonts, google-chrome

I installed texlive 2010 and ran `fc-cache -fvs` to update font cache. After that some fonts are not displaying properly in google chrome. In firefox it is working fine. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot?  For awhile I was running into a font issue where Chrome was butchering fonts with a `text-shadow` set, but that could be a completely different issue.

Comment: I have attached the image now

Comment: Ouch, that's much worse than what I was thinking of...

Comment: Did you try purging and then re-installing Chrome

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: Yes I'm still having the issue :(

Comment: I've just haved this same issue, but with firefox and just after installing texlive.... :_( I'm trying removing everything from texlive.. but I don't have much faith...

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding the Chromium Nightly ppa:chromium-daily/ppa and see if you can replicate the issue. Please let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this :

http://www.binarytides.com/display-hindi-unicode-fonts-on-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.